# Javascript: How can I conditionally use Object.keys() to push specific keys into an array?

Tags: javascript

I have an object, let's say:

```
var stateValues = {
  CA: 423,
  MI: 90,
  IL: 200,
  OH: 56,
}
```

I want to put only the abbreviated states into an array if their values are below 100. I am using forEach() combined with Object.keys to try to do this. Can you please have a look at my code and tell me what I am doing wrong? Please advise me with ways to do with functional programming only because I must use functional programming for this problem.

Here's my attempt:

```js
var stateValues = {
  CA: 423,
  MI: 90,
  IL: 200,
  OH: 56,
}

function lowState(state) {
  if (stateValues[state] < 100000) {
    return Object.keys(stateValues);
  }
}
var lowerSumStates = stateValues.forEach(lowState);
```

Comment: Use `Array#filter` and `Object.entries` instead.

Comment: Another note: `Array.prototype.forEach` is (almost?) always the wrong thing to use if you are doing the functional programming (tm)

Answer (score 1):

If you combine keys, filter, and map, you can get your result that you're looking for.

```
var stateValues = { CA: 423, MI: 90, IL: 200, OH: 56 };
var lowerSumStates = Object.keys( stateValues )
      .filter( key => stateValues[key] < 100 )
      .map( key => stateValues[key] );
```

https://jsfiddle.net/gtfaqdbt/

Answer (score 1):

```js
"use strict";

var stateValues = {
  CA: 423,
  MI: 90,
  IL: 200,
  OH: 56
};

function lowState(arr) {
  var [state,val]=arr;
  if (val < 100)
    return state;
}

var lowerSumStates = Object.entries(stateValues).map( lowState ).filter(v=>v);

console.log(lowerSumStates);
```

Here's the gist:

- `Object.entries` takes the object and builds a two-dimensional array of key/val pairs
- `map()` iterates over the array and calls your function
- because `entries` is multidimentional, the argument to your function is an array of key and value, thus you can restructure it using the ES6 restructuring assignment (e.g., `var [foo,bar]=[1,2]`) *this isn't necessary, you could have worked with `arr[1]` and `arr[0]`, but this is more maintainable
- if the value is less than 100, it returns the state abbreviation, otherwise it will return undefined (because that's what `map` does), leaving you with an array like `[undefined,'MI',undefined,'OH']`
- then you can easily remove the undefined by filtering on truthy values

Answer (score 0):

```
Object.keys(stateValues)
      .filter(key => stateValues[key] > 100)
      .map(key => stateValues[key])
```

Comment: One might do better without using free variables :-) `Object.entries(stateValues).filter(kv => kv[1] < 100).map(kv => kv[0])`

Comment: Cool. Add it as an answer?

Comment: I don't like code-only answers, they are (usually) not reusable.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is `foreach` can only be used with arrays. And you're trying `foreach` with object which is undefined for sure. So try using `for` instead:

```js
var stateValues = {
  CA: 423,
  MI: 90,
  IL: 200,
  OH: 56,
}

function lowState(stateValues) {
    var resultArray=[];
    for (var state in stateValues) {
      if (stateValues.hasOwnProperty(state) && stateValues[state] < 100) {
          resultArray.push(state);
      }
    }
    return resultArray;
}
var lowerSumStates = lowState(stateValues);
console.log(lowerSumStates);
```